# How can you prevent Entity from erring when a property is null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say that we have a model property that is a collection and null.  Like so.

```
public ICollection<Model> ChildrenById
{
    get
    {
        return Children
            .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Entity while error and say that `Children` is null.  We can get around this by using `if` statements and checking if `Children` is null first, but is there any way to get Entity to return an empty list instead?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the property returning Children never return null.

*edit

Comment: Hey, could you edit your post so I can undo my downvote?  I had a bad day and was being a little mean.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ICollection<Model> ChildrenById
{
    get
    {
        return Children == null 
            ? new List<Model>() 
            : Children
               .OrderBy(c => c.Id)
               .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list itself instead of using a property;

```
Children.Sort((x, y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id));
```

Comment: `Sort` only works on a `List<T>`; which obviously wouldn't work if `Children` is null like stated in the question.